# package inputenc error : unicode character (U+2032)

Tags: latex

I try to write some thing like the following in latex:
"Q" the value of this are(5.2 % , 76.3 %) and the range of "P" are (9.4 % ,55.3%) but I get this error
**package inputenc error : unicode character (U+2032)**
, any help?!

Comment: Have a look at the `siunitx` package to get the spacing between the value and `%` right

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error shows the package `inputenc` finds a [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character where it doesn't expect it. Likely the package expects a [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character. (It's kinda funny, as `inputenc` is actually used to convert different character encodings (including unicode) into the internal latex format. But you clearly have an error.)

Getting unicode characters in your text can happen when you are copy pasting code or text from another application into your latex file.

[The unicode character U+2032 is for the prime (′) symbol](https://codepoints.net/U+2032). Replace it by the ASCII version (likely ' ). Latex processor doesn't like unicode. I don't know what editor you are using, so it is hard to say how to do it in your case.

Ps. You can get latex help on the [Tex stack exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have a `'` in bibliography (biber). I don't want to use `inputenc`. I found it helpful by enclosing it with brackets so `{'}` works.